# What is the fastest method to redirect from one domain to another for optimal page load speed?

Tags: redirect

What is the fastest way to setup a redirect from one domain to another  please guys ?
I mean what method will give the fastest page load speed

i have a domain that had rediects setup in the hpanel to other sites

the speed of loading the target page is 1 or 2 seconds slower (left column)  when compared to the load spead of the target page directly (right column)
when noth urls are tested in gtmetrix. and more requests.

Is the hpanel the best way?   i can install worppress on LS cashe and use a plugin,  or what is the best way please

thanks Kev

Comment: Depending on your requirements and structure of your site, the fastest way probably is doing it via dns, ie point both domains to the same server. This will prevent an unnecessary roundtrip to the first server

Comment: thankyou for your answer  

  what about if the target domain is not my own?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, because you don't have to change anything for the target domain. It would be a problem though, if you can't control the source domain

Comment: yes the source domain is mine  thankyou so much,  
sorry i am not real experienced with this,,,  but "point both domains to the same server."   i guess you are assuming the target domain will be on DNS right?